# mongodb update two array values based on array unique id's

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image: mongodb document]

this is my mongodb document. i want to update comment and likerName field at one query based on comments.user and likerName.likerId. i have done so far this

```
  Tutorial.updateMany(
    { 
      "comments.user":userid
    },
    {
        
      $set:{'comments.$[].profilepic':image}  
    }
).then(data=>{

 // res.send(data);

}).catch(err=>{

  console.log(err);
  
})
```

it updates very well comment field. but i also want to update likerName field same like this.

Answer (score 0):

do u mean?

```
        { 
           $or:[{"comments.user":userid},{"likerName.likerId":userid}]
        },
```